# Meteor: localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_= is blank

Tags: meteor, meta, head

I'm trying to make my meteor app visible to crawlers.
I've added the Spiderable package and installed Phantom.js.
When I to go localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=, it's blank.
When I view the source, it's almost empty, and it ends right before the `<script>` tag that loads the Google Maps API:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/eecc60f7c55db2915697d4beb05274f355ad19e4.css">

<title></title>

<!-- Google Maps -->
</head></html>
```

I haven't encountered any issues with this before, but it got me thinking that maybe I shouldn't be including custom `<scrpit>` (or `<link>`) tags in the app's `<head>`. If this is true - what is the correct way to load external assets? If it's not related to the issue, I'd appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your first question, I am not 100% sure about this being the cause of your problem, but to answer the second, you shouldn't be including scripts/stylesheets in the head of your Meteor application.

Meteor combines all of the client-side js, css, and html for your app, and sends it all together to the client. This means you can just include your stylesheet and scripts in your app's client folder. I would try putting your stylesheets/scripts in the correct place and removing the links in your head and see if that solves your issue.

You can find more detailed descriptions of meteor [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).